# Problem with java bean creation, hibernate and spa

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm having this problem with Spring Tool Suite 4, I've already done an exact same project with it but in this one, it's going bad. I've already reviewed the code hundred times and have no more tips to fix it... I've searched on stack overflow before posting the problem. I found some solutions but in different ways using @Service what isn't my case because this is just the backend of my app. Thanks

There is my model class:

```
package br.unifor.bocume.api.models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "customer_id")
    private Long customer_id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size (max = 80)
    @Column (name = "customer_name")
    private String customer_name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size (max = 80)
    @Column (name = "customer_email")
    private String customer_email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size (max = 200)
    @Column (name = "customer_address")
    private String customer_address;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size (max = 20)
    @Column (name = "customer_cpf")
    private String customer_cpf;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    @Column(name="cc_id", nullable = true)
    private List<CreditCard> ccList; 

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((customer_id == null) ? 0 : customer_id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Customer other = (Customer) obj;
        if (customer_id == null) {
            if (other.customer_id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!customer_id.equals(other.customer_id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    public Long getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(Long customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    public String getCustomer_name() {
        return customer_name;
    }

    public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name) {
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
    }

    public String getCustomer_email() {
        return customer_email;
    }

    public void setCustomer_email(String customer_email) {
        this.customer_email = customer_email;
    }

    public String getCustomer_address() {
        return customer_address;
    }

    public void setCustomer_address(String customer_address) {
        this.customer_address = customer_address;
    }

    public String getCustomer_cpf() {
        return customer_cpf;
    }

    public void setCustomer_cpf(String customer_cpf) {
        this.customer_cpf = customer_cpf;
    }

    public List<CreditCard> getCcList() {
        return ccList;
    }

    public void setCcList(List<CreditCard> ccList) {
        this.ccList = ccList;
    }


}
```

Then, my controller:

```
package br.unifor.bocume.api.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;


import br.unifor.bocume.api.models.Customer;
import br.unifor.bocume.api.repository.CustomerRepository;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customers;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Customer> customersList() {

        return customers.findAll();

    }

    @GetMapping ("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> fetchCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {

        Optional<Customer> customer = customers.findById(id);

        if (customer.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(customer.get());
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Customer addCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        Optional<Customer> myCustomer = customers.findByNameAndCpf(customer.getCustomer_name(), customer.getCustomer_cpf());

        if (myCustomer.isPresent()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Customer already exists");
        }
        return customers.save(customer);
    }

}
```

Finally, my repository:

```
package br.unifor.bocume.api.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.unifor.bocume.api.models.Customer;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    Optional<Customer> findByNameAndCpf(String name, String cpf);


}
```

and the exception is:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-20 12:11:11.903  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] br.unifor.bocume.api.BocumeApplication   : Starting BocumeApplication on diego-macbook with PID 16485 (/Users/diegomota/Projects/workspaces/bocume/bocume/target/classes started by diegomota in /Users/diegomota/Projects/workspaces/bocume/bocume)
2020-03-20 12:11:11.906  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] br.unifor.bocume.api.BocumeApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-20 12:11:11.978  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/diegomota/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/diegomota/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/Users/diegomota/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/Users/diegomota/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/Users/diegomota/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/Users/diegomota/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/Users/diegomota/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2020-03-20 12:11:11.979  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-03-20 12:11:11.979  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-03-20 12:11:12.665  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-03-20 12:11:12.665  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-20 12:11:12.709  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface br.unifor.bocume.api.repository.CustomerRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2020-03-20 12:11:12.709  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 40ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2020-03-20 12:11:12.729  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-03-20 12:11:12.729  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-20 12:11:12.762  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 28ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-20 12:11:13.309  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-20 12:11:13.318  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-20 12:11:13.318  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-20 12:11:13.404  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-20 12:11:13.404  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1424 ms
2020-03-20 12:11:13.526  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 6.0.8 by Redgate
2020-03-20 12:11:13.535  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-20 12:11:13.841  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-20 12:11:13.869  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bocume (MySQL 8.0)
2020-03-20 12:11:13.905  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.017s)
2020-03-20 12:11:13.919  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema `bocume`: 02
2020-03-20 12:11:13.921  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema `bocume` is up to date. No migration necessary.
2020-03-20 12:11:14.047  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-20 12:11:14.117  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-20 12:11:14.224  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-20 12:11:14.327  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-03-20 12:11:14.939  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-20 12:11:14.945  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-20 12:11:15.194  WARN 16485 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.unifor.bocume.api.repository.CustomerRepository.findByNameAndCpf(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Customer!
2020-03-20 12:11:15.195  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-20 12:11:15.198  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-20 12:11:15.211  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-03-20 12:11:15.213  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-03-20 12:11:15.224  INFO 16485 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-20 12:11:15.233 ERROR 16485 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.unifor.bocume.api.repository.CustomerRepository.findByNameAndCpf(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at br.unifor.bocume.api.BocumeApplication.main(BocumeApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.unifor.bocume.api.repository.CustomerRepository.findByNameAndCpf(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional br.unifor.bocume.api.repository.CustomerRepository.findByNameAndCpf(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the `customer_` prefix from the property names in your `Customer` entity class. As in the log it is mentioned spring is trying to create a query from your repository method `findByNameAndCpf` and while doing so its trying to find property `name` and `cpf` in your `Customer` class and it can not find any property by those names. Or alternatively you can change your method name according to the properties, like `findByCustomer_NameAndCustomer_Cpf`

Comment: Thanks a lot I was Freaking out for hours.. In fact, all my variables weren't in camelCase pattern, I fixed it up... I've committed this silly mistake because I wanted to give the same name as columns in my db for the variables... Living and learning!